# What is the recommended place in SFMC where subscribers's custom user-preferences for emails should be stored (i.e. custom email subscription center)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, subscriber, user-profile, preference-center

**Goal:** I am looking into creating a custom user-preference center for subscribers in SFMC (to manage email preference - like offer email, newsletter emails, etc - i.e. custom email subscription center).

Based on the initial research and reading all the salesforce help documentations, I think I have come to a conclusion that creating a custom user-preferences page is the way to go (due to limitations of out of the box preference center).

In order to create custom preferences, I am seeing 2 ways?

**option 1)** Go to "Preference Management" > add new preferences then make use of Lists / Groups etc to manage those preference

- limitation: I am not seeing an easy way to query lists / groups in sql queries, audience segmentation etc.

**option 2** I have not seen this anywhere but I "think" saving custom preferences in data extension is going to be the ideal place (fields - subscriberkey, preference1, preference2, etc)

This option will give the most flexibility where is can be joined with AllSubscribers 1:1 relationship and can easily be used in sql queries / segmentation for inclusion / exclusion of customers based on their preference.

**Question** - 1) Am I on the right tracking thinking custom preferences should be saved in a data extension?

2) In this case, just confirming that I don't have to add preferences in "Preference Management", at all, correct? and no more use of lists / groups etc?

3) With the data extension approach, I am aiming to use AllSubscribers to manage the subscriber status only and use data extension for managing user-preferences for email. Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, Data Extensions are the way to go. The List model is outdated and I haven’t seen anyone use it in years.

*1) Am I on the right tracking thinking custom preferences should be saved in a data extension?*

Yes

*2) In this case, just confirming that I don't have to add preferences in "Preference Management", at all, correct? and no more use of lists / groups etc?*

Correct

*3) With the data extension approach, I am aiming to use AllSubscribers to manage the subscriber status only and use data extension for managing user-preferences for email. Is this a good practice?*

Yes, that’s correct. I would advise to only use All Subscribers for managing the general active/unsubscribe status, eg. when someone wants to unsubscribe from all emails, then this should be noted in the All Subscibers list and it will automatically prevent them from receiving any emails. Anyone else who has not specifically asked to be unsubscribed from all emails, should be active in All Subscribers.

For all more granular preferences, like opt into one type of email and opt out of another type of email, Data Extensions will be just fine.

Before you implement this, think through how your users would be using this data to actually send emails out - in general, I prefer to have a dedicated Data Extension for every email type, so that users can easily use it for sending, but if your approach is different you might be able to use one bigger DE to store all preferences in one place.

For reference and to get you started on coding this, take a look at this Trailhead module: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/custom-preference-center-development

And if you need to integrate with Sales/Service Cloud, I have an article on my blog that should help: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/01/14/custom-profile-and-subscription-center-integrated-with-sales-service-cloud/

Comment: Hi zuzannamj thank you for the detailed explanation and answering my question. How to start from scratch for all existing subscribers? Meaning I get it, I will need to make a decision if I want all subscribers to be opted in or opted out by default. Do I need to create a record / row for all existing subscribers with that default value in the preference DE? Or DEs should be used to only save either true OR false, not combination of both? Just trying to think how I will display current value of optin (true or false) on a web page when some subscriber may exist in DE or some may not?

Comment: It depends on your legal requirements and what data you are required to keep. I’d probably go for one DE per communication, where I’d only keep the opted-in subscribers so that marketers can easily use it. And on top of that, I’d keep one big additional DE as a log, where I’d keep all status changes along with dates etc. so that everything can be tracked back. I don’t know your exact requirements, so it’s best if you discuss the design with your team, as this is more about business than technical logic.

Comment: If you keep opted in subscribers only in DE then if someone optin and then opt outs, do you delete the row from the DE?

Comment: Yes thats right, but that’s one of many possibilities, you should do a proper discovery with the business owners of the process

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how easy / difficult it is to manage email frequency in SFMC with this custom preference solution? By email frequency, I am referring to allowing customers to select - no emails for 30 days or 60 days etc. I can imaging that will require managing a separate DE and whoever pick hat option, creating  a SSJS job that unsubscriber / delete rows from optin preference DE then add after X days. Just thinking about that sounds like a lot more complexity.

Comment: One more question, for custom preferences, there is no way to capture those preferences in any platform reporting, right? Like for each campaign level, reporting how many subscribers opted in for option A and opted out, how many for option B and so on...

Comment: I’d keep frequency capping as a completely different process and not touch the preference DEs - I’d use either a SendLog or the Sent data views along with exclusion scripts for frequency capping and not touch the preference DEs - but that’s a completely new, big topic, so please post this as a separate question in case you get stuck.

Comment: If you keep this info in your logging DE, then it’s possible to report on it

Comment: I am exploring some options and one option is to go with hosting preference center on a custom page of the website (not a SFMC cloud page). That can use API to to update SFMC data extension fields. I am wondering if unsubscribe from all event is triggered by API, is that event going to be recorded within campaign tracking report? Like how we see in tracking campaignABC had X opens, Y click and Z unsubscribes. How a custom page will detect the campaign for which unsub event is being triggered?